# Using react natives picker

Tags: react-native

I am trying out picker in my react native project and this example i took directly from the react native docs

```
<CardItem>
<Item  floatingLabel>
<Label>Airtime Amount</Label>
<Picker selectedValue={this.state.language} onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({language: lang})}> <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" /> <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" /></Picker>
</Item>
</CardItem>
```

This is the source http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html

I get the error

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.language')
```

How can i correct this.
    render

My class starts like this

```
class Form extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    openDrawer: React.PropTypes.func,
  }
....
```

Comment: do you have the language created on the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to creat the language and give a value

```
constructor(props) {
  super();
  this.state = {
    language: 'english', // or language: '',
  }
}
```

Comment: After adding the constructor the error goes but i get a textfield instead of a picker.

Comment: Are you using native base ?  maybe the Item is doing that try to remove and just use the basic example from the react native docs just to see if it works